# Why <v-stepper/> component not working properly in vuetify nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm using `vuetify3` in `nuxt3`, some code work but when a try to use the `<v-stepper>...</v-stepper>` component i get the following error :

```bash
✔ Nitro built in 533 ms
                                                                                                nitro 17:34:04
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-stepper
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

I want to understand why. This is the code I used from the [official doc](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/) :

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <v-stepper v-model="e1">
            <v-stepper-header>
            <v-stepper-step
                :complete="e1 > 1"
                step="1"
            >
                Name of step 1
            </v-stepper-step>

            <v-divider></v-divider>

            <v-stepper-step
                :complete="e1 > 2"
                step="2"
            >
                Name of step 2
            </v-stepper-step>

            <v-divider></v-divider>

            <v-stepper-step step="3">
                Name of step 3
            </v-stepper-step>
            </v-stepper-header>

            <v-stepper-items>
            <v-stepper-content step="1">
                <v-card
                class="mb-12"
                color="grey lighten-1"
                height="200px"
                ></v-card>

                <v-btn
                color="primary"
                @click="e1 = 2"
                >
                Continue
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn text>
                Cancel
                </v-btn>
            </v-stepper-content>

            <v-stepper-content step="2">
                <v-card
                class="mb-12"
                color="grey lighten-1"
                height="200px"
                ></v-card>

                <v-btn
                color="primary"
                @click="e1 = 3"
                >
                Continue
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn text>
                Cancel
                </v-btn>
            </v-stepper-content>

            <v-stepper-content step="3">
                <v-card
                class="mb-12"
                color="grey lighten-1"
                height="200px"
                ></v-card>

                <v-btn
                color="primary"
                @click="e1 = 1"
                >
                Continue
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn text>
                Cancel
                </v-btn>
            </v-stepper-content>
            </v-stepper-items>
        </v-stepper>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        e1: 1,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

#### My `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
    build: {
      transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    vite: {
      define: {
        'process.env.DEBUG': false,
      },
    },
})
```

#### My `plugins/vuetify.js`

```js
// plugins/vuetify.js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

#### My `package.json`

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --port=8001",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "cross-env PORT=8001 node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you used and your nuxt config that enables Vuetify. Even better would be a link to a reproduction to the problem (e.g., in StackBlitz).

Comment: Vue components should not be self-closing. Do this: `<v-stepper>...</v-stepper>`

Comment: Hi dear @tony19 thanks for the comment, I've edited the post adding more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same Problem with some Vuetify3 tags. It`s because of "Beta release" i mean. the next Release (Titan) should be soon published thats written on official Vuetify site. Well done im exited..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Stepper component is not supported in Vue 3. If you check vuetify documentation for version beta 3.0 you can see the list of supported components.

Answer (score 2):

The stepper component has not been included in the newest version of Vuetify. They plan to reintroduce the component in the near future (Q3 2023). You can check this out in
[the official Vuetify roadmap](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/roadmap/) page.

Answer (score 2):

as long as vuetify 3.4 release is pending, you can use v-stepper (as part of the "labs" components) beginning from vuetify 3.3.11 by manually importing it:

```
<script setup>
  import { VStepper } from 'vuetify/labs/VStepper'
</script>
```